# Storing Many Booleans in Android

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a known number of checkboxes (e.g. 100). I want to be able to store these so that I can read them at runtime (and repopulate the checkboxes). I would prefer using SharedPreferences for the storage.

What is the best way to store/retrieve these boolean values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to save state of those checkboxes in the same activity context then mantain a boolean `ArrayList` and if you want them again when you run your application next time or something else than `SharedPreferences` is a better way for this.

I have written a sample code:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                            "CheckBoxStates", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

editor.putBoolean("CheckBox1", mCheckBox1.isChecked());
editor.commit();
```

As your have many CheckBoxes so simply you can use a loop condition here.

Comment: But how would I save it to sharedpreferences? What datatype should i use?

Comment: @joseph: check updated answer. Simply you have to use a Boolean data type.

Comment: figured you meant that. But I think that might create a performance issue. Or would it? Is it quicker to use West_Link and parse myself, or use yours and let shared preferences parse it?

Comment: @Joseph: Though SharedPrefrences is also a XML based storage and android handle it automatically. And @Wes_Link idea is also an option but I am not sure how could you identify a perticular checkbox in that case.

Answer (score 1):

store all boolean values in a string that contain a comma seperated 0-1 sequence, for example: "1,0,1,1," means "true,false,true,true"